# What do I add to requirements.txt for font awesome (font-awesome)

Tags: font-awesome

SO yeah I'm pretty new to this I used font-awesome for some icons (free version) but after i tried to deploy it to heroku it got some errors, I highly suspect that it is due to requirements.txt, can anyone tell me what I should write in there? I tried font-awesome-free==16.0 but that didnt really work...

Answer (score 1):

Kind of this requirements.txt. You can create

```
Flask==0.8
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
certifi==0.0.8
chardet==1.0.1
distribute==0.6.24
gunicorn==0.14.2
requests==0.11.1
```

So that it could fetch or default will work. This is an example

Comment: always :) @TitaniumTronic